# Are sponsored tags immune from burnination?

Tags: support, burninate-system, sponsored-tags

Are sponsored tags, that is, tags for which a third party has paid for a sponsorship, eligible for burnination if they otherwise meet the regular criteria for burnination? If so, what happens to the sponsorship? Does the sponsoring party get a prorated refund (e.g. "You sponsored this for the entire year of 2019. It was burninated at the end of September, so here is 25% of your money back.")?  Do they get a free transfer to a new tag?

I'm not asking about any specific tag, but in general.

Comment: I don't think they can. Unless tags created by some users, they are usually chosen more wisely.

Comment: [Renames of sponsored tags are already up for CM approval](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/46443007#46443007) so I guess burninations are even harder to get going.

Comment: Let's wait until it actually happens.  That will be a long wait.

Comment: I don't know. Let's try burning one and find out. Any suggestions? I'm eyeing [[tag:facebook]].